# sql select statement by choosing min timestamp value

Tags: sql, db2

i'm having data as below in table

```
NUM_SER           STATUS     TIMESTAMP             
----------------  ---------  --------------------- 
00000000000000d1  02         2/21/2012 12:24:13 PM 
00000000000000d1  05         2/21/2012 5:49:46 PM  
00000000000000d2  01         2/21/2012 11:05:36 AM  
00000000000000d2  05         2/21/2012 10:27:57 PM  
00000000000000d2  03         2/21/2012 4:55:13 PM  
00000000000000d3  02         2/21/2012 3:18:23 PM  
00000000000000d3  05         2/21/2012 7:02:09 PM  
00000000000000d3  02         2/21/2012 7:16:03 PM
```

I want select query statement which will select data for each serial number with min timestamp value for selected date,

so the expected result when selection date is 2012-02-21

```
NUM_SER           STATUS     TIMESTAMP             
----------------  ---------  --------------------- 
00000000000000d1  02         2/21/2012 12:24:13 PM     
00000000000000d2  01         2/21/2012 11:05:36 AM   
00000000000000d3  02         2/21/2012 3:18:23 PM
```

how this can be done, i try to use min(TIMESTAMP) but get err 'An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT"'

Comment: For what database?  And what have you tried?

Comment: Does the timestamp column actually have a 'PM' and 'AM' value at the end?

Comment: this is DB2, SELECT NUM_SER,STATUS,MIN(TIMESTAMP) FROM ICGR1100_H, this is the sql i tried, there is no PM/AM, just for explanation i insert it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from t t1
left join t t2
on t1.num_ser = t2.num_ser and t1.timestamp > t2.timestamp
where t2.timestamp is null
```